# Using late 2015 iMac as second screen of a M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, screen-sharing, monterey

I have a 21.5-inch, late 2015 iMac running macOS Monterey 12.1 and a M1 MacBook Pro running the same macOS version.

When I'm using the iMac, I have the option to mirror the screen of the iMac on the MacBook Pro (and the option to use it as separate screen). However, when I'm using the MacBook, it doesn't appear to the iMac as a target for screen mirroring. The same occurs to my iPad and iPhone: the iMac is not a target for the screen mirroring.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

Comment: Nope, because my iMac is late 2015 and does not meet the requirements

Comment: Then you just answered your own question. If it does not meet the requirements it won't work.